# Simple bubblesort algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have been learning C++ over the last couple of days. I know a few other programming languages well, and it hasn't been horribly difficult. I would appreciate any comments on my code so that I may improve:

- Readability
- CPP "style"
- Efficiency
- Vector vs array--which is better in this case?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

```
//Bubblesort algorithm
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define pass ;

int main()
{
    // int unsorted[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int length;
    int max;
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::cout << "Please input how many numbers you want to sort and the max value on those numbers: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> length;
    std::cin >> max;
    int unsorted[length];
    int count = -1;
    while(count++<length)
    {
        unsorted[count] = rand()%max;
    }
    //int length = sizeof( unsorted ) / sizeof( int );
    int i = 0;
    int num_changes_per_loop = 1; /* Should be set to zero at the beginning of each loop, but is nonzero here to prevent the loop from being cancelled on the first iteration */
    int general_loop_count = 0;
    while(general_loop_count++<length)
    {
        if(num_changes_per_loop==0) { break; }
        for(i=0;i<length-1;i++)
        {
            int current_value = unsorted[i];
            int adjacent_value = unsorted[i+1];
            if(adjacent_value > current_value) {pass}
            else if(current_value > adjacent_value) {
                std::cout << "These two values need to be switched!" << std::endl;
                int tmp = adjacent_value;
                unsorted[i+1] = current_value;
                unsorted[i] = tmp; 
                num_changes_per_loop++;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        std::cout << unsorted[i] << ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read [How to implement classic sorting algorithms in modern c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c)

Answer (score 4):

## Vector vs raw array

When dealing with arrays that have a length know at run-time, you usually use an `std::vector`, it is cleaner and safer w.r.t the memory allocation (for dynamicity). When the size of the array is known at compile-time, consider using an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is the C++ way of using raw arrays.

In this case, I'd use an `std::vector` and a [`.reserve(length)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) call

## Array out of bound

Here is a concrete argument to why you should use a `vector`: you are actually writing/reading outside of you array, which can fail immediately (if you are lucky), or can fail way later in your code (if you're unlucky).

```
int count = -1;
while(count++<length)
{
    unsorted[count] = rand()%max;
}
```

if you have `length == 1` for example, here is what will happen, 'unwrapping' the while:

```
int count = -1;
if (count++ < 1) // count == -1, so count < 1 is true ; after that we increment count by 1, so count == 0 
{
    // accessint unsorted[0]
    unsorted[count] = rand()%max;
}
if (count++ < 1) // count == 0, so count < 1 is true ; after that we increment count by 1, so count == 1 
{
    // accessint unsorted[1], which is outside of the array
    unsorted[count] = rand()%max;
}
// after that, the condition is false
```

## For loops vs while loops

Twice in your code, you have a while loop looking like this one:

```
int count = -1;
while(count++<length)
```

When you iterate this way, you usually see a for loop instead:

```
for(unsigned int count = 0 ; count < length ; ++count)
```

which does (almost) the same thing, but is more readable.

Note that the starting value is 0, leading into one less iteration than previously. However, it is actually the *last* iteration that is removed

## *Pass*

In your main loop, you are using your *pass* macro. As [jvb mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/165538/139838), you usually want to avoid to use macros ([as the faq iso cpp says](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-token-pasting)). Moreover, in this particular case, you may consider two alternatives:

- Using the [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) keyword
- Reverting your condition

In this case, the second alternative is way better, as it is easy to put into place (the keyword `continue` shouldn't be used unless other alternatives are awkward).

```
if(adjacent_value > current_value) { continue; }
else if(current_value > adjacent_value) {
    // ...
}
```

would become

```
if(adjacent_value < current_value) {
    // ...
}
```

because you are really doing something only if the above condition is fulfilled

## Swapping values

To swap your values, you are using your custom code

```
int tmp = adjacent_value;
unsorted[i+1] = current_value;
unsorted[i] = tmp;
```

which works well.

However, you may consider using the function [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), that swaps two values:

```
std::swap(unsorted[i], unsorted[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the std::stream operations, there's not much C++ to see... yet ;) But that will come, over time. So, you definitely should try out a `std::vector`. One of its advantages is that it encapsulates data *and* the item count... you can ask the `vector` for its `size()`.

The pass `#define`... please don't do that. All this preprocessor stuff is handled even *before* the compiler will see the source code; and the preprocessor has - in a manner of speaking - a very bad grasp of language syntax. In the long run, you are bound to get very strange compile-/runtime-errors with stuff like that (...just imagine to find out after hours of debugging that someone somewhere has called a function *pass*).

In any language, it's recommended to check user input. If anyone will enter a "-1" for length, what will `int unsorted[length];` do? Of course, that depends (but probably horrific things). Any dimension should be of an unsigned type, or (even better) `size_t`.

The naming could be improved - "unsorted" maybe is a little bit misleading - as the *sorted* final result will be in "unsorted" ;)

The "general_loop_count"-thing is a little bit strange. Usually, if one feels the urge to add comments like *"should be set to zero at the beginning..."*, something is less from ideal. I usually write it like that (as follows), but of course you may find your own style. But it's always nice not to litter variables.

```
while(true) {
    unsigned changes=0;
    // ...sort loop here
    if (!changes) break;
}
```

For similar reasons, it's somewhat unusual (and a little bit dangerous) to declare an index variable *i* somewhere and to reuse it in different `for` loops through the program. The usual technique is to have a local counter like `for(int i=0; i<length; i++)`... which is available only in the loop body.

Strictly speaking, there is no need to have current_value/adjacent_value variables... at least one can get rid of tmp here. While sorting `int`, this is not of much importance, but imagine sorting (heavy) `std::string` or even larger things... it makes sense to minimize the copying operations.

And a final `std::cout << std::end` might give a nicer output.